# Clicking an Button on a page through Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am tring to write chrome extension to auto my work,
i tring to click on a button on my exension and then let the script click on 3 buttons on the website, one of them as class or id by the name: "activityFeedExpandCollapseIcon"
for somereason its not working, hope to get somehelp.

i have tried serach the forum nothing works.

## popup.Html:

```
<!doctype html> 
<style>
h1{
text-align:middle;
align:middle;
}
button{
background-color:white;
height:50px;
width:100px;
font-family:david;
font-style:bold;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:300;
}

.body{
 width:120px;
}
</style> 
<html>  
    <head><title>HelpDesk SaleForce Helper</title></head>  
<body>
 <div class="body">
    <div class="right">
    <h1>Change Type</h1>
    <button id="Incident">Change to Incident </button>
    <button id="request">Change to Request </button>
    </div>
    <div class="left">
    <h1>Foward</h1>
    <button id="B7"> Forward to B7 </button>  
    <button id="Sdom">Forward to Sdom </button>
    <button id="Rotem">Forward to Rotem </button>   
    <button id="NH">Forward to NH </button>
    <button id="TLV">Forward to TLV </button>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
        //and inject the script in it
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "content_script.js"});
    });
}

document.getElementById('request').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

## Content_script.js

```
function clickrequest() {
    var request = document.getElementsByClassName("activityFeedExpandCollapseIcon");


    request.click();
}

clickrequest();
```

## Manfiest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Help Desk SalesForce Helper",  
    "description": "Wow",  
    "version": "1.0",    
    "permissions": [    
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "*://*/*",
    "https://icl--bmcservicedesk.eu14.visual.force.com/*"
    ] ,

    "browser_action": { 
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icons/19.png",
            "38": "images/icons/38.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"  
    },

    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icons/16.png",
        "19": "images/icons/19.png",
        "38": "images/icons/38.png",
        "64": "images/icons/64.png",
        "128": "images/icons/128.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to run your content script's code in the console?  `document.getElementsByClassName("activityFeedExpandCollapseIcon ")` should return an array, not something clickable.  Also, your manifest mentions a background script and asks for far more permissions than you need, but that may be because you've trimmed out that for your question.

Comment: @Teepeemm ok i have edit the menfist,
so how can i choose a button in the web that when i click my button on the extension, the button in the web will be clicked?
why document.getElementsByClassName("activityFeedExpandCollapseIcon ") is worng?

Comment: There is a space after `activityFeedExpandCollapseIcon `. I think this may be an issue.

Comment: @Misir Jafarov Yes i saw. still not working.
my code is good? nothing missing?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('sidebarHideButton')[0].click();

works on consile. but when i put it on the extension i get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: What does `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('sidebarHideButton'))` show for the console and the extension?

Comment: nothing, empty.

Comment: found the answer:
```
var theButton = document.querySelector('.sidebarShowButton');  //a shorter way to select the first element of a class
if (theButton) {
    // if the element is present in this context, click on it.
    theButton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer:

```
 var theButton = document.querySelector('.sidebarShowButton'); //a shorter way to select the first element of a class if (theButton) { // if the element is present in this context, click on it. theButton.click(); }
```

and allFrames:false in the popup.js